# Insufficient system memory in resource pool 'default' in a database set to compatibility level 150

Tags: sql-server, compatibility

This is a rather bizarre issue and I hope I'll find a way to explain it that makes sense.

One of our clients whose SQL Server database is On Premises complained that one element of our software was "not working". When I investigated the matter I found that the software was hanging on a SQL Scalar function.

This is the function. The crazy thing about it is that, although it isn't a well written function (so please ignore that), this function

- does not access any tables in the database, but merely manipulates a few scalar variables before returning a result
- does not contain any loops or recursion

And yet it hangs

```
    CREATE FUNCTION
           [dbo].[ky_NETFNGetNumericalFormat]
          (@VALUE     DECIMAL(38, 9),
           @LENGTH    INT,
           @DECIMALS  INT)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
    AS
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @V30 VARCHAR(30)

      IF @VALUE IS NULL
        BEGIN
          RETURN ''
        END

    DECLARE @DEC0 DECIMAL(20, 0)
    DECLARE @DEC1 DECIMAL(21, 1)
    DECLARE @DEC2 DECIMAL(22, 2)
    DECLARE @DEC3 DECIMAL(23, 3)
    DECLARE @DEC4 DECIMAL(24, 4)
    DECLARE @DEC5 DECIMAL(25, 5)
    DECLARE @DEC6 DECIMAL(26, 6)
    DECLARE @DEC7 DECIMAL(27, 7)
    DECLARE @DEC8 DECIMAL(28, 8)
    DECLARE @DEC9 DECIMAL(29, 9)

    IF @DECIMALS = 0
      BEGIN
        SET @DEC0 = CONVERT(DECIMAL(20, 0), ROUND(@VALUE, 0))
        SET @V30 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @DEC0)
        IF LEN(@V30) > 3
          BEGIN
            SET @V30 = LEFT(@V30, LEN(@V30) - 3) + ',' + RIGHT(@V30, 3)
          END
        IF LEN(@V30) > 7
          BEGIN
            SET @V30 = LEFT(@V30, LEN(@V30) - 7) + ',' + RIGHT(@V30, 7)
          END
        IF LEN(@V30) > 11
          BEGIN
            SET @V30 = LEFT(@V30, LEN(@V30) - 11) + ',' + RIGHT(@V30, 11)
          END
        IF LEN(@V30) > 15
          BEGIN
            SET @V30 = LEFT(@V30, LEN(@V30) - 15) + ',' + RIGHT(@V30, 15)
          END
        IF LEN(@V30) > 19
          BEGIN
            SET @V30 = LEFT(@V30, LEN(@V30) - 19) + ',' + RIGHT(@V30, 19)
          END
        RETURN @V30
      END

    IF @DECIMALS = 1
      BEGIN
        SET @DEC1 = CONVERT(DECIMAL(21, 1), ROUND(@VALUE, 1))
        SET @V30 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @DEC1)
      END

    IF @DECIMALS = 2
      BEGIN
        SET @DEC2 = CONVERT(DECIMAL(22, 2), ROUND(@VALUE, 2))
        SET @V30 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @DEC2)
      END

    IF @DECIMALS = 3
      BEGIN
        SET @DEC3 = CONVERT(DECIMAL(23, 3), ROUND(@VALUE, 3))
        SET @V30 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @DEC3)
      END

    IF @DECIMALS = 4
      BEGIN
        SET @DEC4 = CONVERT(DECIMAL(24, 4), ROUND(@VALUE, 4))
        SET @V30 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @DEC4)
      END

    IF @DECIMALS = 5
      BEGIN
        SET @DEC5 = CONVERT(DECIMAL(25, 5), ROUND(@VALUE, 5))
        SET @V30 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @DEC5)
      END

    IF @DECIMALS = 6
      BEGIN
        SET @DEC6 = CONVERT(DECIMAL(26, 6), ROUND(@VALUE, 6))
        SET @V30 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @DEC6)
      END

    IF @DECIMALS = 7
      BEGIN
        SET @DEC7 = CONVERT(DECIMAL(27, 7), ROUND(@VALUE, 7))
        SET @V30 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @DEC7)
      END

    IF @DECIMALS = 8
      BEGIN
        SET @DEC8 = CONVERT(DECIMAL(28, 8), ROUND(@VALUE, 8))
        SET @V30 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @DEC8)
      END

    IF @DECIMALS = 9
      BEGIN
        SET @DEC9 = CONVERT(DECIMAL(29, 9), ROUND(@VALUE, 9))
        SET @V30 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @DEC9)
      END

    IF @DECIMALS > 9
      BEGIN
        RETURN CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @VALUE)
      END

    IF LEN(@V30) > 4 + @DECIMALS
      BEGIN
        SET @V30 = LEFT(@V30, LEN(@V30) - 4 - @DECIMALS) + ',' + RIGHT(@V30, 4 + @DECIMALS)
      END
    IF LEN(@V30) > 8 + @DECIMALS
      BEGIN
        SET @V30 = LEFT(@V30, LEN(@V30) - 8 - @DECIMALS) + ',' + RIGHT(@V30, 8 + @DECIMALS)
      END
    IF LEN(@V30) > 12 + @DECIMALS
      BEGIN
        SET @V30 = LEFT(@V30, LEN(@V30) - 12 - @DECIMALS) + ',' + RIGHT(@V30, 12 + @DECIMALS)
      END
    IF LEN(@V30) > 16 + @DECIMALS
      BEGIN
        SET @V30 = LEFT(@V30, LEN(@V30) - 16 - @DECIMALS) + ',' + RIGHT(@V30, 16 + @DECIMALS)
      END
    IF LEN(@V30) > 20 + @DECIMALS
      BEGIN
        SET @V30 = LEFT(@V30, LEN(@V30) - 20 - @DECIMALS) + ',' + RIGHT(@V30, 20 + @DECIMALS)
      END
    RETURN @V30

    END
```

Now please don't worry about what this function does (and it does it badly - it even contains a parameter that is never used (**rolleyes**) as I have since rewritten the function and it no longer hangs. So I can address the problem.

So.... why am I asking this question if I resolved the issue anyway?

**I want to know what is going on.** Aside from the crazy logic in the function I cannot see any reason why this specific function should cause a problem. If **this** function causes a problem, another function might as well. **Is there anything in this function that one should be careful of in SQL Server 2019, and why?**

Here's a bit of salient information: When I looked at the database Options in SQL Server Management Studio I saw that the database Compatibility Level was set to "SQL Server 2019 (150)"

**When I changed the Compatibility Level down to "SQL Server 2017 (140) the problem went away**

When I changed the compatibility level back to "SQL Server 2019 (150)" I noticed something else. Look at the final few IF statements in the function, starting with

```
    IF LEN(@V30) > 4 + @DECIMALS
```

I commented all of those out and recreated the function and it ran to completion, even on Compatibility Level SQL Server 2019. Then I reintroduced the statements, one IF statement at a time.

With every IF statement it would take longer for the function to run..... BUT ONLY the first time. If I ran it again a second time it would return results instantaneously, as one would expect from a function that's that simplistic.

As I reinstated more of those IF statements the function would take longer and longer to run **the first time**, until eventually it would no longer run to completion but return the error stated in the title.

Once I reinstated enough of the IF statements to cause the error the function would never run successfully again, leading to the issue as reported by the client.

So .... can somebody explain what is going on here, and how to avoid running into this problem.

Oh wait... ONE final bit of info. Looking at an Azure database at the same Compatibility Level, the function was running fine.

Comment: I smell an inlining issue. Has the client updated their version of SQL Server? If, for example, they are still running the RTM version there were several bugs/"features" with the initial inlining of scalar functions implementation.

Comment: Possibly. I am not on the client's server right now, but I reproduced the issue on my developer machine and you seem to be on the right track.... "Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB4583458) - 15.0.2080.9 (X64) 
 Nov  6 2020 16:50:01 
 Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
 Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 22000: ) (Hypervisor)"

Comment: Yep, RTM-GDR. If you try on a more recent CU (CU13 was released on 2021-10-05) do you get the same behaviour? I just gave the function a go on our 2019 Sandbox, which has CU12, and it ran instantly.

Comment: Also you can play with turning that feature on and off with `ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION ... TSQL_SCALAR_UDF_INLINING ...`

Comment: Brilliant.... how would I go about that, just through Windoze updates?!?

Comment: never mind... found it ... I'll let you know how I get on. If this works, please post suggestion so I can award you it as the Answer

Comment: @Larnu please come claim your prize :-) yes you were spot on. I installed CU13 and the problem went away.